# how to change culture date format in c#?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

how to change culture date format in c#

Comment: What kind of application? ASP.NET, WinForms, other?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to you can change the culture for the current thread so you don't have to do it for each call.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("th-TH", False)
```

More information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for this?

[Formatting Date and Time for a Specific Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For example in DateTimePicker you can use CustomFormat property to add the format you want(independent on culture). or see @gcores's answer.